# Dropzone.js not sending file to laravel controller on submit

Tags: php, laravel, forms, dropzone.js

Hi I am trying to integrate Dropzone.js in my app and using Laravel Framework. I have a form with below code,

```
<form method="post" action="{{url('/example/fileupload')}}" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone">

    @csrf


<input type="submit">

</form>
```

The laravel controller attached with this form has below code in which I am just trying to get the name if the image which is dropped in dropzone area,

```
   public function fileupload(Request $request)
    {


 $file = $request->file('file');


$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
echo $filename;

}
```

After clicking submit button it shows me below error,

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Dont know what I am doing wrong here, because when I try to run the same code with simple

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

it shows me the name of the uploaded image file which I want. Any suggestion or fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "Input" class for "Request" ... I believe it will work. The error is being reported because there is no method on the object you are calling.

```
public function fileupload(Request $request)
    {
        $file= $request->file('file');
        $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        echo $fileName;
    }
```

Comment: Bartollo thanks for your reply. but still the same error. I also edited my question with your suggestion.

Comment: @DarazPk see that article https://appdividend.com/2018/05/31/laravel-dropzone-image-upload-tutorial-with-example/